# Contraction Rampage

Tags: contractions

I don't see this getting used quite often, but is it alright to use *chain* contractions in essays, reports, letters, documents, etc.?

> I shouldn't've'd eaten that doughnut.
>
> They'll've a doughnut face if they don't stop.
>
> Oh boy, y'all'll be punished for mistreating that doughnut!

It doesn't break any laws, does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not alright.  Unless it's a character's dialog in which case pretty much anything goes.

That said,

- shouldn't've'd
- They'll've
- y'all'll

shouldn't be used anywhere, as it's not clear what words those are short for.

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought - thanks for the response.

Comment: What do you mean? What could "y'all'll" be short for besides "you all will"?